# How to calculate the sum of "submatrix" entries with numpy/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

I have the following 8x8 matrix in Python, which I have represented as either an 8-by-8 numpy array, or a pandas DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = range(64)

x = np.reshape(x,(8,8)) 

print(x)

# [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7]
#  [ 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
#  [16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23]
#  [24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31]
#  [32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39]
#  [40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47]
#  [48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55]
#  [56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63]]

df = pd.DataFrame(x)

print(df)

#      0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
#  0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
#  1   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
#  2  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
#  3  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31
#  4  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39
#  5  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47
#  6  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55
#  7  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63
```

I'm trying to calculate the sum of the values if it were a 2-by-2 matrix, and replace the above values with this sum. My end result would be

```
#      0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
#  0  216  216  216  216  280  280  280  280
#  1  216  216  216  216  280  280  280  280
#  2  216  216  216  216  280  280  280  280
#  3  216  216  216  216  280  280  280  280
#  4  728  728  728  728  792  792  792  792
#  5  728  728  728  728  792  792  792  792
#  6  728  728  728  728  792  792  792  792
#  7  728  728  728  728  792  792  792  792
```

So, the top corner matrix has a count 216 because

```
0+1+2+3+8+9+10+11+16+17+18+19+24+25+26+27=216
```

Similarly,

```
32+33+34+35+40+41+42+43+48+49+50+51+56+57+58+59=728
4+5+6+7+12+13+14+15+20+21+22+23+28+29+30+31=280
36+37+38+39+44+45+46+47+52+53+54+55+60+61+62+63=792
```

Is there numpy/pandas functionality to make this calculate easier? Especially for much larger matrices whereby manually setting the coordinates of the "sum matrices" could be quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do that with NumPy is this:

```
import numpy as np

def as_submatrices(x, rows, cols=None, writeable=False):
    from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
    if cols is None: cols = rows
    x = np.asarray(x)
    x_rows, x_cols = x.shape
    s1, s2 = x.strides
    if x_rows % rows != 0 or x_cols % cols != 0:
        raise ValueError('Invalid dimensions.')
    out_shape = (x_rows // rows, x_cols // cols, rows, cols)
    out_strides = (s1 * rows, s2 * cols, s1, s2)
    return as_strided(x, out_shape, out_strides, writeable=writeable)

def sum_submatrices(x, rows, cols=None):
    if cols is None: cols = rows
    x = np.asarray(x)
    x_sub = as_submatrices(x, rows, cols)
    x_sum = np.sum(x_sub, axis=(2, 3))
    x_rows, x_cols = x.shape
    return np.repeat(np.repeat(x_sum, rows, axis=0), cols, axis=1)

x = np.arange(64).reshape((8, 8))

print(sum_submatrices(x, 4))
# [[216 216 216 216 280 280 280 280]
#  [216 216 216 216 280 280 280 280]
#  [216 216 216 216 280 280 280 280]
#  [216 216 216 216 280 280 280 280]
#  [728 728 728 728 792 792 792 792]
#  [728 728 728 728 792 792 792 792]
#  [728 728 728 728 792 792 792 792]
#  [728 728 728 728 792 792 792 792]]

print(sum_submatrices(x, 2))
# [[ 18  18  26  26  34  34  42  42]
#  [ 18  18  26  26  34  34  42  42]
#  [ 82  82  90  90  98  98 106 106]
#  [ 82  82  90  90  98  98 106 106]
#  [146 146 154 154 162 162 170 170]
#  [146 146 154 154 162 162 170 170]
#  [210 210 218 218 226 226 234 234]
#  [210 210 218 218 226 226 234 234]]

print(sum_submatrices(x, 2, 8))
# [[120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120]
#  [120 120 120 120 120 120 120 120]
#  [376 376 376 376 376 376 376 376]
#  [376 376 376 376 376 376 376 376]
#  [632 632 632 632 632 632 632 632]
#  [632 632 632 632 632 632 632 632]
#  [888 888 888 888 888 888 888 888]
#  [888 888 888 888 888 888 888 888]]
```

*EDIT:* [As pointed out by Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51827019/1782792), [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) is faster that [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) here, so the improved version of the function above would be:

```
def sum_submatrices(x, rows, cols=None):
    if cols is None: cols = rows
    x = np.asarray(x)
    x_sub = as_submatrices(x, rows, cols)
    x_sum = np.sum(x_sub, axis=(2, 3), keepdims=True)
    x_sum = np.broadcast_to(x_sum, x_sub.shape)
    return x_sum.transpose((0, 2, 1, 3)).reshape(x.shape)
```

Which is essentially the same as Divakar's answer, only that one is nicer since it does not use stride tricks and transposing.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm a bit confused by the above use of `as_strided()`. How would one set up, as opposed to four 4x4 matrices above, 16 2x2 matrices?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang I have rewritten the answer to be more generic and added another example. You can pick any submatrix size, as long as it divides well, and they do not even need to be square.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a generalized solution using `einsum` and `np.repeat` (the one condition being that `n` evenly divides the array):

```
def sum_chunks(n, x):
    """
    Tiles an array into NxN chunks, based on the sum of the chunk
    :param n: dimension of sub-matrices
    :param x: input array
    :return: Tiled array
    """
    h, w = x.shape
    out = x.reshape(h//n, n, -1, n).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1, n, n)
    s = np.einsum('ijk->i', out)
    return np.repeat(np.repeat(s.reshape(h//n, w//n), n, axis=0), n, axis=1)
```

You may use this solution to split your array into any size subarray, sum, and repeat to the original size:

```
>>> sum_chunks(4, np.arange(64).reshape(8,8))
array([[216, 216, 216, 216, 280, 280, 280, 280],
       [216, 216, 216, 216, 280, 280, 280, 280],
       [216, 216, 216, 216, 280, 280, 280, 280],
       [216, 216, 216, 216, 280, 280, 280, 280],
       [728, 728, 728, 728, 792, 792, 792, 792],
       [728, 728, 728, 728, 792, 792, 792, 792],
       [728, 728, 728, 728, 792, 792, 792, 792],
       [728, 728, 728, 728, 792, 792, 792, 792]])
```

```
sum_chunks(2, np.arange(64).reshape(8,8))
array([[ 18,  18,  26,  26,  34,  34,  42,  42],
       [ 18,  18,  26,  26,  34,  34,  42,  42],
       [ 82,  82,  90,  90,  98,  98, 106, 106],
       [ 82,  82,  90,  90,  98,  98, 106, 106],
       [146, 146, 154, 154, 162, 162, 170, 170],
       [146, 146, 154, 154, 162, 162, 170, 170],
       [210, 210, 218, 218, 226, 226, 234, 234],
       [210, 210, 218, 218, 226, 226, 234, 234]])
```

Comment: 'arr' above is the array 'x' in the post?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang i updated my answer with a generalized function to help you out with different sized sub-arrays

Comment: Could you check the above is correct? `sum_chunks(4,4, x)` doesn't appear to give the intended sum for my input

Answer (score 3):

Here's something with performance in mind that leverages `np.broadcast_to` to do the replication part after summing up with reshaping -

```
def sum_chunks_broadcasted(x, M, N): # M,N : no. of blocks along height and width
    m,n = x.shape
    s = x.reshape(M,m//M,N,n//N).sum((1,3),keepdims=1)
    return np.broadcast_to(s,(M,m//M,N,n//N)).reshape(m,n)
```

Sample run -

```
In [143]: x = np.arange(48).reshape(8,6)

In [144]: x
Out[144]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
       [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41],
       [42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47]])

In [145]: sum_chunks_broadcasted(x, M=2, N=3) # 2x3 total windows
Out[145]: 
array([[ 76,  76,  92,  92, 108, 108],
       [ 76,  76,  92,  92, 108, 108],
       [ 76,  76,  92,  92, 108, 108],
       [ 76,  76,  92,  92, 108, 108],
       [268, 268, 284, 284, 300, 300],
       [268, 268, 284, 284, 300, 300],
       [268, 268, 284, 284, 300, 300],
       [268, 268, 284, 284, 300, 300]])
```

**Timings**

Comparing against the other generic vectorized ones by [`@user3483203's sum_chunks`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51826446/) and [`@jdehesa's sum_submatrices`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51826143/) on large arrays for various window shapes and numbers  -

1) Setup input array :

```
In [83]: x = np.random.rand(8000, 8000)
```

2) 4x4 total windows :

```
In [152]: %timeit sum_submatrices(x, 8000//4, cols=8000//4)
1 loop, best of 3: 271 ms per loop

In [153]: %timeit sum_chunks(8000//4, x)
1 loop, best of 3: 372 ms per loop

In [154]: %timeit sum_chunks_broadcasted(x, M=4, N=4)
10 loops, best of 3: 81 ms per loop
```

3) 40x40 total windows :

```
In [155]: %timeit sum_submatrices(x, 8000//40, cols=8000//40)
1 loop, best of 3: 271 ms per loop

In [156]: %timeit sum_chunks(8000//40, x)
1 loop, best of 3: 385 ms per loop

In [157]: %timeit sum_chunks_broadcasted(x, M=40, N=40)
10 loops, best of 3: 84 ms per loop
```

4) 400x400 total windows :

```
In [158]: %timeit sum_submatrices(x, 8000//400, cols=8000//400)
1 loop, best of 3: 318 ms per loop

In [159]: %timeit sum_chunks(8000//400, x)
1 loop, best of 3: 396 ms per loop

In [160]: %timeit sum_chunks_broadcasted(x, M=400, N=400)
10 loops, best of 3: 123 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Using numpy this can also be done like so (not the prettiest):

```
dx = 8
dy = 8
x_subs = 2
y_subs = 2

arr = np.arange(dx * dy).reshape(dy, dx)
sums = [
    [second_split.sum() for second_split in np.split(first_split, y_subs, axis=1)]
    for first_split in np.split(arr, x_subs, axis=0)
]
sums_filled = np.repeat(np.repeat(sums, dx, axis=0), dy, axis=1)
```

I'm not familiar with 'stride tricks', but this solution is likely similar to 
jdehesa's.